# How to replace "&" with "&amp;" except when already part of an XML entity?

Tags: shell, sed, xml

I have a file (xml) with many `&amp;/&lt;/&gt;/etc`, but sometimes also some `&` characters by themselves. I want to change this symbol to `&amp;` without replacing the others.

```
cat file.xml | sed s/"&amp;"/"&"/g | sed s/"&"/"&amp;"/g > new_file.xml
```

This does not work, because it also replaces the `&`s found in `&amp;`, `&gt;` for example.

How to do it?

Comment: Put a section of your file. Of course update your post.

Comment: Do you really want to allow blanks like `&am p;`, `&lt ;`?

Comment: No, I put blanks because stack change this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could first escape the `&` when found in an entity, and then substitute the remaining ones. Like:

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/_/_u/g; # use _ as an escape character. Here escape itself
              s/&\([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*;\)/_a\1/g; # replace & with _a when in entities
              s/&\(#[0-9]\{1,8\};\)/_a\1/g; # &#1234; case
              s/&\(#x[0-9a-fA-F]\{1,8\};\)/_a\1/g; # &#xabcd; case
              s/&/\&amp;/g; # now convert the non-escaped &s
              s/_a/\&/g;s/_u/_/g; # restore escaped & and _'
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/&(?!#?\w{1,31};)/&amp;/g'
```

That one is a bit more lax than the `sed` one in that it would consider as XML entity anything that starts with `&`, an optional `#` and any number (up to 31) of alnums (or underscores) and `;`, while the `sed` one would be more explicit in what an entity is (as in `&#blah;` would not be considered as an entity). In practice, it's not likely to make a lot of difference.